# Can my SQLITE schema define a default value based on other column values?

Tags: sqlite, schema

The question basically says it. I want the last four columns of a table to use the data entered in the first three to assign a default value on a row insert (a concatenation of 4 columns) . Is this possible?

Comment: No. This is not possible in ANSI SQL and not possible in SQLite's [mostly] sub-dialect. Triggers can be used, but these are not "default values".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with a [trigger](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) that updates the record directly after is has been inserted:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTable_col4_default_value
AFTER INSERT ON MyTable
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NEW.col4 IS NULL
BEGIN
    UPDATE MyTable
    SET col4 = NEW.col1 || NEW.col2 || NEW.col3
    WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid;
END;
```